# Check if string is empty didn't work

Tags: java, android, string

In my android application i have two `activity` :

- Player_List
- Game_Launch

In the first `activity`, I ask the name of the `player`, if all names are empty we play without names, but if they're not empty we play with `players`.

When I add 3 out of 4 players, I have the `activity` with the `player`. But he add the player who is `empty`.

How can I make a `check system`?

Player_List:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Game_Launch.class);

            i.putExtra("player1", player1.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("player2", player2.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("player3", player3.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("player4", player4.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
```

Game_Launch :

```
Intent in = getIntent();
        String player1= in.getExtras().getString("player1");
        String player2= in.getExtras().getString("player2");
        String player3= in.getExtras().getString("player3");
        String player4= in.getExtras().getString("player4");
        //Log.d();

        if (!player1.equals("")) {
            playerge= new String[] {"player2", "player3", "player4"};
        }
        else if (!player2.equals("")){
            playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player3", "player4"};
        }
        else if (!player3.equals("")){
            playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player2", "player4"};
        }
        else if (!player4.equals("")){
            playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player2", "player3"};
        }
        else if (!player1.equals("") && (!player2.equals(""))){
            playerge= new String[] {"player3", "player4"};
        }
        else if (!player3.equals("") && (!player4.equals(""))){
            playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player2"};
        }
```

When I use this check it doesn't work. Can you help me to solve my problem? Thank you.

EDIT :

```
With answerd i have tried :


Intent in = getIntent();
    String player1 = in.getStringExtra("player1");
    String player2 = in.getStringExtra("player2");
    String player3 = in.getStringExtra("player3");
    String player4 = in.getStringExtra("player4");

    //Log.d();

    if (!player1.equals("")) {
        playerge= new String[] {"player2", "player3", "player4"};
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "p1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     else if (!player2.equals("")) {
        playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player3", "player4"};
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "p2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (!player3.equals("")) {
        playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player2", "player4"};
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "p3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (!player4.equals("")) {
        playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player3", "player2"};
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "p4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tout ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

My String 1 is completed, 2 not, 3 completed, 4 completed but i have P1 toast.

How String was created :

```
public void checkuser(){
    EditText player1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText player2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText player3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText player4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String f = player1.getText().toString();
    String f1 = player2.getText().toString();
    String f2 = player3.getText().toString();
    String f3 = player4.getText().toString();

    if ((f.trim().equals("")) && (f1.trim().equals("")) && (f2.trim().equals("") && (f3.trim().equals("")))){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Game_Launch_withoutplayer.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else{
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Game_Launch.class);

        in.putExtra("player1", player1.getText().toString());
        in.putExtra("player2", player2.getText().toString());
        in.putExtra("player3", player3.getText().toString());
        in.putExtra("player4", player4.getText().toString());
        startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic you want to achieve here. Like when player1 is empty what should happen, etc

Comment: I have 4 `edittext`. When i click on my `button` i check if my `EditText` was `empty`. If it's `empty` we will play without name ; else we will play with `player`. But if the player have completed `player1`, `player2`, `player3` without `player4` i want remove player4 from my string.

Comment: So at a time any only one player's name can come up empty? (since you are using `if-else` thats why I'm asking)

Comment: If `player1` is not `empty`, i send `player1`, `player2`, `player3`, `player4`. It's on the second `activity` i check who is `empty` for remove it from my `string`. It's why i use `if-else` in the second activity.

Comment: So, here: `if (!player1.equals("")) {
        playerge= new String[] {"player2", "player3", "player4"};
        ... } ` ... Shouldn't you check if `player1` is empty (because you are removing it)...shouldn't the condition be: `if (player1.equals("")) {...}`

Comment: Oh, thank you. Now all work. Thank you very much for your time and your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the data incorrectly. When you write data like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Game_Launch.class);
i.putExtra("player1", player1.getText().toString());
```

You get it as:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String player1= in.getStringExtra("player1");
```

Now you can do your comparisons as it is.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i have another problem about `'getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' in 'android.content.Intent' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'`. I'll try to resolve it. Thank you very mush for your answerd

Comment: @johnsnow85 yeah thats my bad...I was incorrect..Just remove the second argument (`""`) from `in.getStringExtra("player1", "")`;

Comment: @johnsnow85 `in.getStringExtra("player1")` returns `null` if no string found

Comment: After somes tries, that didn't work too... I have edited first post

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
if(player1.equalsIgnoreCase("") && (!TextUtil.isempty(player1)) )
```

And get Data as below:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String player1= in.getStringExtra("player1");
```